# Decayed tooth: what is the natural history if left untreated?

Tags: tooth-decay

I always wondered how the human organism manages tooth decay if left untreated.  After a tooth decays and breaks off, all that remains are the roots, and sometimes a cyst is formed.  Assuming lack of dentistry, over the course of years, what will the gum do to the roots?  Does it treat it as a foreign body?

I have tried to find any information regarding this question. There are many resources that have plenty information, but I was unable to find information how the body deals with the subject. Or at least I was unable to find it.

Comment: Hi Vedran, your question fundamentally is interesting, so I fixed the question to be closer to site guidelines. But you didn't refer to the research you've done so far trying to answer your own question, and as a veteran of StackExchange you know that's part of the standards of asking a Q.  Please edit and add what you've found.

Comment: Also see the [ask] page.

Comment: I have edited the question, however still I was unable to find the information on the web.

Comment: No, it won't treat it as a foreign body, why would it? Keep in mind that once you have RCT (root canal therapy) the tooth is basically dead. So what's the difference?

Comment: I do not have background in medical, but from what I know the moment it looses function and starts decaying, it becomes a foreign body.

Comment: @VedranMaricevic. That is incorrect. The bacteria causing the decay will be treated as foreign bodies, but the tooth itself will not.

Comment: Exactly - I left that in the question when I edited it because it's an incorrect assumption by definition of "foreign body," and I wanted that to be addressed in whatever answer was given.